# mysql is it possible to have a recurring statement in a view

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a view for a comments table. In one of the cells it counts how much comments a comment has. This how the original table looks

```
+--+-------------------------------------+----------------+----------------+
|id|comments                             |commentOnContent|commentOnComment|
+--+-------------------------------------+----------------+----------------+
|1 |this is a comment                    |24              |0               |
+--+-------------------------------------+----------------+----------------+
|2 |this is a reply to that comment      |0               |1               |
+--+-------------------------------------+----------------+----------------+
|3 |this is another reply to that comment|0               |1               |
+--+-------------------------------------+----------------+----------------+
|4 |this is a reply to a reply           |0               |3               |
+--+-------------------------------------+----------------+----------------+
```

This is how the view looks

```
+--+-------------------------------------+-------+----------------+----------------+
|id|comments                             |replies|commentOnContent|commentOnComment|
+--+-------------------------------------+-------+----------------+----------------+
|1 |this is a comment                    |0      |24              |0               |
+--+-------------------------------------+-------+----------------+----------------+
|2 |this is a reply to that comment      |0      |0               |1               |
+--+-------------------------------------+-------+----------------+----------------+
|3 |this is another reply to that comment|0      |0               |1               |
+--+-------------------------------------+-------+----------------+----------------+
|4 |this is a reply to a reply           |0      |0               |3               |
+--+-------------------------------------+-------+----------------+----------------+
```

for the comment with an id of 1 the replies cell should equal three because it has two repliesas well as a reply to one of its replies. i can see how much replies it has with a simple statement `select count(*) from comments where commentOnComment = id;`. however if i want to add the the number of replies on its replies and replies on its replies on its replie im assuming that i would have to do some sort of recursive function but some of you may know that the problem is that stored functions can be in a view but cannot be recursive and stored procedures can be recursive but cant be in a view.

**So in a nutshell the question is, is there any possible way to have a recursive statement to solve this problem of counting how many replies and replies on replies each comment has?**

Comment: Yes.  But not in MySQL.  So I guess the answer is "no" in your case.  Most other databases support recursive CTEs which would enable this functionality.

Comment: Thanks, any suggestions?

Comment: @GordonLinoff mysql v8.0 will support recursive CTEs

Comment: @JevonMcPherson you really could have searched on SO, there are several questions dealing with hierarchical data within mysql.

Comment: apologies, i didn't have the correct wording to create an adequate search as i wouldn't have typed in hierarchical data. but this is very useful nonetheless.